# How to create a single table from multiple tables on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want to combine a large number of tables from different tabs into a master table in a new tab, and calculate the number of rows from each source table.
The tables contain the same table structure

---

Consider the following inputs -

```
Table A (in Sheet1)      Table B (in Sheet2)   Table C (in Sheet3)  
----------------         -------------         -------------  
a11 a12 a13              b11 b12 b13           c11 c12 c13
a21 a22 a23              b21 b22 b23
a31 a32 a33

- Value a11 is in cell 'Sheet1!A2' and value b11 is in cell 'Sheet2!A2' and so on
- All rows below Table A,B,C are empty
```

I would like resultant tables like this -

```
Result Table 1           Result Table 2
---------------          ---------------
a11 a12 a13              Sheet1 3
a21 a22 a23              Sheet2 2
a31 a32 a33              Sheet3 1
b11 b12 b13
b21 b22 b23
c11 c12 c13
```

---

I have around 30 input tables in 30 sheets that are updated daily.

Any Sheets formula or script that can create the master table?

Comment: Please share your code as well. What all you have tried to achieve the result?

Answer (score 1):

A simple Google search would direct you to [something like this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/FZBH-2YZFMs). Adjusting that to your usecase would result in something like the code below:

```
={RANGE_SHEET_1; RANGE_SHEET_2; RANGE_SHEET_3}
```

Same goes for [the amount of rows in a sheet](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/3qsR2m-1Xx8)